# Read last known value in a Excel data table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cron

I'm working on something but can't figure out a formula and wondered if anyone out there has any suggestions?

I'm looking for a formula which will tell me the last status of a job.
In the example below it shows 2 jobs. (Job no. 123456-1 & Job no. 123456-2)
[image: Excel data table screenshot]

- Job no. 123456-1 has been at status 1,2 and 3 but then goes back to status 1 and then onto status 2 so it's last known status is status 2.
- Job no. 123456-2 has been at status 1,2,3 & 4 and but then goes back to status 3 so it's last known status is status 3.

As the data is collected via a bar code scanner it appends the data to next empty row below the current data.

I want to be able to type in the relevant job number and the formula to look up the latest known status of the job.

Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through simple conditional formatting.  Take a look at my example below:

[image]

First, I use the formula:

```
MAX(IF(A:A=D2,ROW(A:A),0))
```

Which will return the maximum row number to which the condition is true. In Excel if you press Ctrl + Shift + Enter after you submit your formula, Excel will treat the returned value as an array rather than a single value.

Using this Row number, then we simply look it up using an Index command:

[image]

Notice the curled brackets around it. This is due to pressing Ctrl + Shift + enter first.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!!!!!! Works a treat!!! Many thanks for your time. :-)